# TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#

I'm stuck! I have this code

```
System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography pointLefttop = h.GreenPoly == null || h.GreenPoly.PointCount < 4 ? null : h.GreenPoly.PointAt(1);
System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography pointRighttop = h.GreenPoly == null || h.GreenPoly.PointCount < 4 ? null : h.GreenPoly.PointAt(2);
DbGeography linestringBack = pointLefttop == null || pointRighttop == null ? DbGeography.LineFromText("LINESTRING(0 0, 0 0)", 4326) : System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.LineFromText("LINESTRING(" + pointLefttop.Longitude + " " + pointLefttop.Latitude + ", " + pointRighttop.Longitude + " " + pointRighttop.Latitude + ")", 4326);
```

Where `h.GreenPoly` has value `{SRID=4326;POLYGON ((-112.51643746 33.49170131, -112.51694319 33.4917729, -112.51685776 33.49219669, -112.51635201 33.49212509, -112.51643746 33.49170131))}` and it's type is `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography`

But the line where I calculate `linestringBack` throws an exception

```
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I've tried replacing it with

```
DbGeography linestringBack = pointLefttop == null || pointRighttop == null ? DbGeography.LineFromText("LINESTRING(0.0, 0.0)", DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId) : System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.LineFromText(
                                    string.Format("LINESTRING({0} {1}, {2} {3})",
                                    pointLefttop.Longitude.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), pointLefttop.Latitude.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), pointRighttop.Longitude.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), pointRighttop.Latitude.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                                    , DbGeography.DefaultCoordinateSystemId);
```

but I'm still getting the same error and I can't figure out the cause. Any ideas?

EDIT:

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]
[image: Image4]

Comment: There's nothing that could potentially throw `TargetInvocationException` in the code you've posted. Maybe within the code used in the last piece, there's something that uses `System.Reflection`?

Comment: What will the string `("LINESTRING(" + pointLefttop.Longitude + " " + pointLefttop.Latitude + ", " + pointRighttop.Longitude + " " + pointRighttop.Latitude + ")"` look like when evaluated? Does it have a comma for decimal separators by any chance?

Comment: @rene   "LINESTRING(-112.51643746 33.49170131, -112.51694319 33.4917729)"

Comment: What does the top of the stack trace look like?

Comment: @rene I've updated my question. Added screenshots

Comment: @Dana Copy the contents of a StackTrace from the exception and post it as a text here in question contents.

Comment: You always have to look at the exception's InnerException property to know what went wrong.  It clearly shows a BadImageException.  Lots of existing questions at SO talk about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. It seemed that it was a problem regarding Microsoft.SqlServer.Types. I was using version 11 and it worked after updating it to 14 (tested in VS2015 and VS2017)

For those who perhaps will have the same problem:

1. Right click on your project -> Manage NuGet packages...
2. In the search tab (Installed area) type `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`
3. Click on it and update to version 14
4. Search everywhere is used `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` like `Web.config` file and change `newVersion` to `14.0.0.0`